# Exclude folders from builds in Brocfile

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-cli, broccolijs

Is there a way to exclude a folder from a build in a Brocfile (or any other place).
The use case is packaging, where I have an app made of sub-apps within pods. eg.

```
/app/modules/components
/app/modules/app1
/app/modules/app2
/app/modules/app3
```

I'd like to build them all when environment is set to 'development' or only eg. 'app1' when environment is 'app1'. Any suggestions?

I have tried different combinations of broccoli-file-remover, broccoli-funnel and broccoli-merge-trees to no avail.

```
var removeFile = require('broccoli-file-remover');

module.exports = removeFile(app.toTree(), {
    paths: ['app/modules/pod1/', 'app/modules/pod2/']
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ah, so after actually thinking about this clearly, everything is actually working exactly as expected in my previous example.

I clearly wasn't paying enough attention. `app.toTree()` is far too late to perform this operation, as everything has already been built and concated.

Luckily, ember-cli does enable addons to modify the appropriate trees at various life cycle milestones.

See: https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-cli/blob/master/ADDON_HOOKS.md for more details on which hooks are currently available.

The hook that should do the trick is `Addon.prototype.postprocessTree`. Now we have two choices, we can build a standalone addon, via `ember addon` or we can create a light-weight in-repo addon via `ember g in-repo-addon`. Typically for these types of situations, I prefer in-repo-addons as they don't require a second project, but otherwise they are the same.

1. ember g in-repo-addon remove
2. we need to install broccoli-stew via `npm install --save broccoli-stew`
3. include it `var stew = require('broccoli-stew')`;
4. add hook postprocessTree to the add-on
5. when the postprocessTree is for the type we care about, use broccoli-stew to remove the directories we no longer care care.

The resulting pull request: https://github.com/WooDzu/ember-exclude-pod/pull/1

> Note: I noticed `template` wasn't one of the types available in postprocess, so I added it: https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-cli/pull/4263 (should be part of the next ember-cli release)
>
> Note: we really do want an additional hook
>   `Addon.prototype.preprocessTree`, as to ignore the files before we
>   even build them. I have opened a related issue:
>   https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-cli/issues/4262

**output of the above steps**

```
var stew = require('broccoli-stew');

module.exports = {
  name: 'remove',

  isDevelopingAddon: function() {
    return true;
  },

  postprocessTree: function(type, tree){
    if (type === 'js' || type === 'template')   {
      return stew.rm(tree, '*/modules/pod{1,2}/**/*');
    } else {
      return tree;
    }
  }

};
```

Comment: is it possible to not run these steps during tests

Comment: Like removing, is there a way to exclude a particular folder from being watched for changes i.e., exclude a folder for live reload?

Comment: this no longer works after updatinf ember-cli from 3.3.0 to 3.4.0

Answer (score 3):

I am pretty confident broccoli-stew's rm will handle this correctly.

https://github.com/stefanpenner/broccoli-stew/blob/master/lib/rm.js#L4-L40 there are even tests that test a very similar scenario: https://github.com/stefanpenner/broccoli-stew/blob/master/tests/rm-test.js#L48-L57

```
var stew = require('broccoli-stew');
module.exports = stew.rm(app.tree(), 'app/modules/{pod1,pod2}');
```

If this doesn't work, feel free to open an issue on broccoli-stew. Be sure to provide a running example though

Comment: Hi @Stefan. No joy so far. I've created a repository to reproduce the issue, shall I report in broccoli-stew or broccolli-funnel which appears to be used internally in stew.rm()?

Answer (score 0):

This is really late, but I created a Broccoli plugin to do just this. It's available at https://www.npmjs.com/package/broccoli-rm.

(The trick is to detect whether an excluded path is a folder, and then use a glob match to make sure that none of the children of the folder get symlinked during copying.)

```
var rm = require('broccoli-rm');
var input = app.toTree();
module.exports = output = rm([input], {
   paths: ['app/modules/pod1', 'app/modules/pod2']
});
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.