# Exclude folders from builds in ember cli

Tags: ember-cli, broccolijs

How can I exclude some of the specific folder while building the application for production.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Exclude folders from builds in Brocfile](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30686368/exclude-folders-from-builds-in-brocfile)

Comment: can you please share me any working sample code