# Ember: exclude folders from ember-cli-build

Tags: ember.js

Is there a way to exclude folders from an ember-cli build - so you can put some working code in it and not have it compiled?

I've seen a few similiar questions on stack overflow eg [Exclude folders from builds in Brocfile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30686368/exclude-folders-from-builds-in-brocfile) but this seems to be talking about a pod structure which I'm not using. I would have thought that this should be simple to achieve, but haven't found any solution as of yet.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Put that kind of code outside of the `app` folder, and then manually copy it with `broccoli-funnel` and `broccoli-merge-trees`.

Comment: Many thanks - should have tried that!